# wpa_supplicant reply to any command with UNKNOWN COMMAND

Tags: android, linux, wifi, wpa-supplicant, miracast

While sending a command to wpa_supplicant ( with wpa_cli for instance ) I got UNKNOWN COMMAND all times.

```
root@rk3399_box:/system/bin # wpa_cli 
wpa_cli v2.5-devel-6.0.1
Copyright (c) 2004-2015, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi> and contributors

This software may be distributed under the terms of the BSD license.
See README for more details.


Using interface 'wlan0'

Interactive mode

> scan
UNKNOWN COMMAND
```

And then if I specify the IFNAME it works

```
> IFNAME=wlan0 scan
OK
IFNAME=wlan0 <3>CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=3 BSSID=00:00:00:00:00:00 SSID=
IFNAME=wlan0 <3>CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=0 BSSID=00:00:00:00:00:00 SSID=
```

That's an issue, as I can't just send the IFNAME as Android SDK is just setting it while it's a p2p interface but not with the others: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/net/wifi/+/refs/tags/android-6.0.1_r74/service/java/com/android/server/wifi/WifiNative.java#129

I've another device that's almost the same, that works properly sending commands without the IFNAME parameters.

What makes this fail?

Comment: Hi forlayo, Can you fix and find the solution. Same issues facing now. Can you please help?